# WCF Service VS IIS 7.0 VS IIS7.5

Tags: wcf, iis-7, iis-7.5, memory-leaks

I got WCF Service with Fluent NHibernate. When I host it in in IIS7.5 on my development machine(WIN7) it works fine. Worker process shows the clear garbage collection indication of my app pool.

But when I moved to production, which is a Windows Server 2008 with IIS7, Garbage collection is not working, and the virtual bytes in worker process keeps on increasing and got out of memory.

The app pool is configured as Integrated .net 2.0. Has anyone experienced this, or is it a known issue with IIS7.0, or do I miss any settings in my configuration file?

I already tried with timely recycling but it did not have any effect.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

There are some references to garbage collection running less often on windows 2008 IIS7, than on a development machine, see for example: [GC Not Running Often Enough on IIS 7 Application - Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463009/gc-not-running-often-enough-on-iis-7-application-windows-server-2008)

However, if you are hitting this problem your code is written in such a way that objects are left for the garbage collection to clean up. You should try disposing objects and suppressing finalizations, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx especially the code example at the end of the article.